# Add option for editors through `register_setting`

Tags: editor, options

I want to add some options in wordpress admin panel which editors also can update through a form. I have used `register_setting()` function to add those options.

For administrator this works fine, but for editors i get message `Sorry, you are not allowed to manage these options.`. Is there a way so editors can also edit these new options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow users with capabilities other than `manage_options` to save a setting you can use the [`option_page_capability_{$option_page}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_page_capability_option_page/) hook. Despite the name, `{$option_page}` is the option *group*, which is what you set for the first argument of `register_setting()` and `settings_fields()` on your options page.

So if you registered a setting:

```
register_setting( 'wpse_310606_setting_group', 'wpse_310606_setting' );
```

You can allow other capabilities to save it with:

```
function wpse_310606_setting_capability( $capability ) {
    return 'edit_pages';
}
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_wpse_310606_setting_group', 'wpse_310606_setting_capability' );
```

Editors and Administrators both have the `edit_pages` capability, so this would allow both roles to save this settings group.